# Selenium Keeps opening up firefox browser when I want to use phantomjs

Tags: java, maven, selenium, firefox, phantomjs

I am creating a framework in Java in Eclipse using selenium (2.53) and Selenide. I am trying to use Phantomjs to run my scripts. But every time, I execute my project, firefox will open up and the following error message will show up:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary
FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on 
port 7055; process output follows: 
4   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
```

This occurs with the following code:

```
open("Link);
```

In my starting class, I have the following code to instantiate the phantomjs driver.

```
Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"Path/phantomjs.exe");
```

Comment: please don't ruin the formatting of the post. Your orignal one was hard to read, so I edited it. Don't change it again

Comment: You need to show much more code! What is your `WebDriver` instantiated as?

Comment: please add the rest of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest of code was done with Selenide. This part was done with pure selenium. The two weren't compatible together.